# how to have the c# wpf webbrowser control load mobile version of websites

Tags: c#, wpf, controls, browser, mobile-website

I have a simple WPF application with a webbrowser control. When I direct the control to load a page I'd like to have the control tell the server it's trying to load the page from that it's a mobile device and therefore load the smaller version of the page. I know a lot of sites just add mobile before the address, so google.com's mobile page is just mobile.google.com, but I'm wondering if there is a way to load the have the web server automatically direct my webbrowser control to the mobile version of the site? I feel like there should be a very simple way to do this, but I just can't figure it out :).

Thanks in advance!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will generally be controlled by the site using the [User Agent](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/User_agent), which is not something you can change with the standard WebBrowser control. There is an alternative WPF webbrowser control, based on [Chromium](http://code.google.com/chromium/), which you can download from [CodePlex](http://wpfchromium.codeplex.com/). It might not support User Agent spoofing out of the box, but it's open source so you can manually change it in the code to an iPhone, Windows Mobile etc.

Comment: Very clear answer. I was going to say you need to set the user agent to a phone based UA, however I was unaware that you couldn't easily change the UA.

Answer (score 10):

Actually, the WebBrowser does support changing the User Agent via headers in the Navigate method:

```
this.yourWebBrowserControl.Navigate( new Uri( "http://www.yoursite.com" ), string.Empty, null, string.Format( "User-Agent: {0}", "Your user agent string here" ) );
```

Comment: I think you might be the only person on stack overflow to have ever posted a correct answer to this question...

Comment: that's right. it doesn't work. the user defined UA string gets overwritten

Answer (score 1):

I know this is old, but this is an easy thing to do:

First you need the user agent string and it needs to be string formatted. This is how I do it below
wbMobile is a webbrowser control. This example will take you to the mobile bing website

```
wbMobile.Navigate(new Uri("http://m.bing.com/", UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute), string.Empty, null, string.Format("User-Agent: {0}", "Opera/9.80 (J2ME/MIDP; Opera Mini/9 (Compatible; MSIE:9.0; iPhone; BlackBerry9700; AppleWebKit/24.746; U; en) Presto/2.5.25 Version/10.54"));
```

This will navigate to the webpage using a mobile user agent string and allow you to view mobile websites on the fly in the webbrowser control

Answer (score 0):

Boydski's solution was not the right one for me.
Best solution for this case:

[Changing the user agent of the WebBrowser control](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/937573/changing-the-user-agent-of-the-webbrowser-control)

But sometime the "navigator.userAgent" is not set with header - solution.
In this case you have to use **UrlMkSetSessionOption**. 
[MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms775125(v=vs.85).aspx)

```
// import .. use a internal static class like "Native" ;)
[DllImport("urlmon.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Ansi)]
internal static extern int UrlMkSetSessionOption(int dwOption, string pBuffer, int dwBufferLength, int dwReserved);

// usage
string userAgent = "Mozilla/5.0 (iPhone; U; CPU iPhone OS 4_3_3 like Mac OS X; en-us)";

UrlMkSetSessionOption(0x10000002, null, 0, 0);

UrlMkSetSessionOption(0x10000001, userAgent, userAgent.Length, 0);
```

Proper user agent strings you can find [here](http://useragentstring.com/pages/Mobile%20Browserlist/)

Have fun!