# Specify User Agent for WPF WebBrowser Control

Tags: wpf, browser, webbrowser-control, iwebbrowser2

I need to alter the default User Agent used by the WPF WebBrowser control. I have looked at the properties of the IWebBrowser2 object behind the control, and tried specifying the user agent by specifying it when calling "Navigate" as [Suggested Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1533429/how-to-have-the-c-wpf-webbrowser-control-load-mobile-version-of-websites/4269600#4269600)

Is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

The solution could be like the following [Changing the UserAgent of the WebBrowser control -Winforms C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/937573/changing-the-useragent-of-the-webbrowser-control-winforms-c)

Answer (score 0):

URLMkSetSessionOption. http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ieinternals/archive/2009/10/08/extending-the-user-agent-string-problems-and-alternatives.aspx