# Web Browser component is IE7 not IE8? How to change this?

Tags: c#, winforms, internet-explorer-8, internet-explorer-7, webbrowser-control

So I have an C# Form application that utilizes the web browser component. Apparently Response.Write(Request.Browser.Version.ToString()); returns "7.0" when I visit my test page from the web browser component.

How can I make this web browser component use IE8?

Comment: I assume that app is running from a PC with IE 8 installed, yea?

Comment: Yes. I've tried it on 3 computers (all are running IE8).

Comment: The answer to this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/937573/changing-the-useragent-of-the-webbrowser-control-winforms-c seems to indicate you need to extend the component in order to set the user-agent that is passed in requests it generates.

Comment: @Amal: you should answer instead of commenting. :)

Comment: @Amal, does changing the user agent, change how the page is rendered? There are some bugs I have with CSS that render correctly in IE8 but not IE7. I don't think just changing the user agent would fix this.

Comment: @Chris - Sorry I wasn't sure if I had understood your question correctly which is why I added a comment rather than answer. looks like Plip came up with the answer you were looking for.

Answer (score 35, accepted):

It appears you need to fiddle with the registry as per this article: -

http://blogs.msdn.com/ie/archive/2009/03/10/more-ie8-extensibility-improvements.aspx

To run a WebBrowser control in IE8 Standards Mode, use the following new value into the registry:

```
[(HKEY_CURRENT_USER or HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE)\Software\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\Main\FeatureControl\FEATURE_BROWSER_EMULATION] 
"MyApplication.exe" = dword 8000 (Hex: 0x1F40)
```

To run in IE7 Standards Mode, use the following registry value:

```
[(HKEY_CURRENT_USER or HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE)\Software\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\Main\FeatureControl\FEATURE_BROWSER_EMULATION] 
"MyApplication.exe" = dword 7000 (Hex: 0x1B58)
```

For IE8 RTM, we’ve added a new “forced” IE8 Standards Mode value. When an application opts into this mode, the Web Browser control will use the IE8 User-Agent string and Browser Emulation mode strictly. It will also ignore fallback features such as the built-in Compatibility View list and the user-generated Compatibility View list when loading pages. To run in “forced” IE8 Standards Mode, use the following registry value:

```
[(HKEY_CURRENT_USER or HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE)\Software\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\Main\FeatureControl\FEATURE_BROWSER_EMULATION] 
"MyApplication.exe" = dword 8888 (Hex: 0x22B8)
```

In all of these examples, “MyApplication.exe” refers to the name of your application.

Comment: Thanks for this. This seems like the only fix. However, I think I'll stick with an IE7 web browser for now.

Answer (score 29):

The answer may come late and might not apply to your case, but according to Ron's answer on the question [WPF .net4 webBrowser and Internet Explorer 8](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3393632/wpf-net4-webbrowser-and-internet-explorer-8#answer-10539827), you can also control the web browser if you have control over the served page:

```
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge"/>
```

While this apparently does not change the user agent, it seems that conditionals like

```
<!--[if lt IE 8]>
```

and CSS `border-radius` are being evaluated properly, indicating that the newest engine (IE 9 on my system) is actually being used despite the user agent reporting MSIE 7.0.

Comment: btw, at other threads people note that you may need to add this meta directly after the <head> element (as first child)

Answer (score 16):

I did follow this and it was not working until I realized it was because I was debugging in visual studio.

On top of setting the registry for your application:

```
Registry.SetValue(@"HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\MAIN\FeatureControl\FEATURE_BROWSER_EMULATION", 
  System.AppDomain.CurrentDomain.FriendlyName, value);
```

You should also set it for your debugging (visual studio hosted) application:

```
Registry.SetValue(@"HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\MAIN\FeatureControl\FEATURE_BROWSER_EMULATION",
  System.AppDomain.CurrentDomain.FriendlyName.Replace(".exe",".vshost.exe"), value);
```

Comment: You can use System.AppDomain.CurrentDomain.FriendlyName to get the application name, rather than hard-coding it.

Answer (score 0):

You should change the registry for your system while you are in debugging too.

```
public void ChangeRegistery()
{
        string key = @"HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\MAIN\FeatureControl\FEATURE_BROWSER_EMULATION";
        var value = 0x22B8;

        Microsoft.Win32.Registry.SetValue(key, System.AppDomain.CurrentDomain.FriendlyName, value,Microsoft.Win32.RegistryValueKind.DWord);
        #if DEBUG 
            Microsoft.Win32.Registry.SetValue(key, System.AppDomain.CurrentDomain.FriendlyName.Replace(".exe", ".vshost.exe"), value, Microsoft.Win32.RegistryValueKind.DWord);
        #endif
}
```