# WPF .net4 webBrowser and Internet Explorer 8

Tags: c#, .net

I have a WPF .net4 app with a webBrowser component that navigates to a local HTML page that uses a CSS file.

When I navigate to the page using IE8 the CSS styling is corrrect, but when I navigate to the page in the webBrowser component the CSS styling is wrong.

Am I wrong in thinking that the webBrowser uses the same activex as IE8? or is there some attribute(s) I have to set in the webBrowser component?

Thanks in advance for any help.

Answer (score 16):

This is probably a little late but I stumbled on to this question in search of other answers.

the WebBrowser control by default renders in quirks mode.  but in your webpage you can specify the version of IE to use to render in the meta data.

```
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge"/>
```

IE=edge instructs the WebBrowser control to use the latest version of IE it supports

Comment: This saved my life and so simple compared to other options! Changing your registry (as seen on other answers to related questions) is not a good option for a developer, specifically in the case you own your webpages, as is my case.

Answer (score 2):

The best explanation that I have heard for this behavior is that the webbrowser control is running in some form of 'compatability' mode.