# IWebBrowser2 object uses IE7 version, instead of the IE version installed on the machine

Tags: windows, internet-explorer, iwebbrowser2

I'm developing on a Win7 machine with IE8 browser (same thing occurs also on IE9).

I've create an application with an *IWebBrowser2* object embedded within a native window.
Within that browser object i execute a javascipt code:

```
  var txt = "Browser Name: " + navigator.appName + "\n";
  txt += "Browser Version: " + navigator.appVersion + "\n";
  alert(txt);
```

and i receive the following alert:  [image]

That confirmed my earlier worries - even when having IE8\IE9 installed on my machine - the *IWebBrowser2* object behaves as if it was **IE7** (including all of the annoying HTML\CSS behaviors).

Does anyone know why this is? or better - if there is any possibility to embed a browser object as IE8\IE9 (for distribution - so it should be legal)

Thanks,

Answer (score 10, accepted):

IE7 is the default rendering mode for embedded IE controls (for compatibility reasons). Use the [FEATURE_BROWSER_EMULATION](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee330730%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) registry key to change that.

Read [Plip's answer over here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1786905/c-web-browser-component-is-ie7-not-ie8-how-to-change-this) or [IEBlog](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ie/archive/2009/03/10/more-ie8-extensibility-improvements.aspx) to get an idea how to do this.