# The web link is loaded in WebBrowser and throws Script error while the link is displayed in IE smoothly

Tags: mfc, iwebbrowser2

I have a MFC application with CWebBrowser embedded.

Currently , I run into an issue :

my browser fails to load some web pages(lack of object , error about JS stuff) and always throws script error while the same web page cab be loaded in IE(10) successfully.

I also try to load it with Firefox and it's OK . So I suppose it is not caused by the page itself .....

As I know , WebBrowser has a parsing engine identical to IE . But why different behaviors ?

Please help me . Thanks in advance .

My OS : Win7 x64 + IE10 .

Comment: You need to implement [FEATURE_BROWSER_EMULATION](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee330730(v=vs.85).aspx). A similar question answered [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6914664/iwebbrowser2-object-uses-ie7-version-instead-of-the-ie-version-installed-on-the/6914709#6914709).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks a lot.

Noseratio gives the correct answer. But his words is tagged as comments and unable to be rated .

Also , as the complement , For X64 version : the registry key is :
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\MAIN\FeatureControl\FEATURE_BROWSER_EMULATION.  I almost give it up because I am routed to : 
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\MAIN\FeatureControl\FEATURE_BROWSER_EMULATION

Plesae refer to the link for details.

http://www.cnblogs.com/philzhou/archive/2012/12/02/2798204.html.