# Running IE8+ on WebBrowser control in C#?

Tags: .net-4.0, browser

I was trying to run webbrowser control and I found that by default it is using IE7 and I tried different fixes like editing registry values or others- none of which worked. I am using .net framework 4.0 and wondering how still the control is stuck with IE7? How can I update the control so that it will be using IE8+ instead of IE7?
Anyone, please help with info

Thanks in advance

Comment: Dup - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1786905/c-sharp-web-browser-component-is-ie7-not-ie8-how-to-change-this

Comment: Those fixes are not working anymore and I already tried those.

Answer (score 0):

Add the following on the line after you open the head

```
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=8" />
```

This will render as IE if installed on the client machine. Alternatively you can use

```
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=Edge" />
```

to render in the highest available IE on the clients machine. If the HTML isn't your own (external) perhaps you could use a pre-load event to add the line to the HTML