# Assigning user agent String to web browser Control

Tags: c#, wpf, webbrowser-control, user-agent

Is there any possibility of assigning user agent string to web browser control in winforms or wpf?

for example i have 3 different web browser controls and each would have different user agent string?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

check this out [Changing the user agent of the WebBrowser control](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/937573/changing-the-useragent-of-the-webbrowser-control-winforms-c)