# Browser application use winform, WebBrowser, C#

Tags: winforms, webbrowser-control, user-agent

I have build browser application use winform, WebBrowser class on C#.

How to set User-Agent, info browser same Firefox, Chrome, Opera browser. Make it like browser common.

Thanks!

Comment: Did u check this ? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5193553/assigning-user-agent-string-to-web-browser-control

Comment: Thanks @Arul Manivannan