# WebBrowser - Tricking websites into thinking it's not IE

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net, browser

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Changing the UserAgent of the WebBrowser control -Winforms C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/937573/changing-the-useragent-of-the-webbrowser-control-winforms-c-sharp)

Is there a way to use the .NET System.Windows.Forms.WebBrowser control and trick a site into thinking the browser is FireFox instead of IE?  I know there are libraries that wrap around other browsers, but I want to continue using WebBrowser.  I want to just change the detected browser so that I can compare the varying responses.

I guess the question behind the question is: Is there a way to change the HttpWebRequest headers, where I believe browser information is stored, prior to navigating to a page?

Comment: See [Changing the UserAgent of the WebBrowser control -Winforms C#](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/937573/changing-the-useragent-of-the-webbrowser-control-winforms-c-sharp)