# Get UserAgent for user's default browser

Tags: c#, browser, user-agent

I'm making an application that contains a `WebBrowser` element and I would like to have the application show the useragent for that user's default browser.

I know how to get both the default browser via Registry keys and how to get the user agent for a browser but cannot figure out how to combine the two. Is this possible?

Comment: Considering that a webbrowser can put anything into its UserAgent (e.g. the current time), then I think you actually need to start the browser to do that reliably. The question is, why do you even want to know this?

Comment: I'm trying to make the application imitate the user's default browser.

Comment: And why do you want to do that? Usually, doing that is not a good idea.

Answer (score 1):

What I would do (of course, this is a bit of an overkill here) is to include a web server and request an URL from this web server, thus getting the user agent.

I.e. roughly this would include:

1. Implement a web server inside the application, e.g. [this one](http://webserver.codeplex.com/)
2. Let the `WebBrowser` control call a local URL of the webserver (e.g. http://127.0.0.1:48384/test)
3. In the web server's request handler, store the user agent into a variable
4. Show this variable to the end user (e.g. in a Label control on your WinForm app or simply by sending a response back from the webserver.

I've successfully used the web server inside my applications several times. One example would by my [HTML edit control](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/43954/ZetaHtmlEditControl) over at the Code Project.

Comment: Sorry, I'm not sure I see how this gets the user agent for the default browser? Wouldn't this return the useragent for the webbrowser, a value I have set.

Comment: Yes, this would return of the `WebBrowser` control. After all, since you mentioned the `WebBrowser` control, I read that you want to get this user agent.

Comment: So how is your mention of `WebBrowser` related to the "default browser" you also mention?

Comment: The useragent of the default browser will be applied to the aforementioned WebBrowser.

Answer (score 0):

Try this(this is a simple function to check if the browser is of a handheld device)

```
string strUserAgent = Request.UserAgent.ToString().ToLower();
bool status = false;
if (strUserAgent != null)
{
    if (Request.Browser.IsMobileDevice == true || 
        strUserAgent.Contains("iphone") ||
        strUserAgent.Contains("blackberry") || 
        strUserAgent.Contains("mobile") ||
        strUserAgent.Contains("windows ce") || 
        strUserAgent.Contains("opera mini") ||
        strUserAgent.Contains("palm"))
    {
        status = true;
    }
}
```

Comment: That's not what is being asked at all.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a pretty simple class to get and set UserAgent.

```
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

public static class UserAgent
{

    [DllImport("urlmon.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Ansi)]
    private static extern int UrlMkGetSessionOption(
        int dwOption, StringBuilder pBuffer, int dwBufferLength, out int pdwBufferLength, int dwReserved);
    [DllImport("urlmon.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Ansi)]
    private static extern int UrlMkSetSessionOption(
        int dwOption, string pBuffer, int dwBufferLength, int dwReserved);

    const int URLMON_OPTION_USERAGENT = 0x10000001;
    const int URLMON_OPTION_USERAGENT_REFRESH = 0x10000002;
    const int URLMON_OPTION_URL_ENCODING = 0x10000004;

    public static string Value
    {
        get
        {
            StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder(512);
            int returnLength;
            UrlMkGetSessionOption(URLMON_OPTION_USERAGENT, builder, builder.Capacity, out returnLength, 0);
            string value = builder.ToString();
            return value;
        }
        set
        {
            UrlMkSetSessionOption(URLMON_OPTION_USERAGENT, value, value.Length, 0);
        }
    }
}
```

I had been looking for a decent way to get UserAgent from windows, as opposed to web, when I found [Changing the user agent of the WebBrowser control](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/937573/changing-the-user-agent-of-the-webbrowser-control)
Inspired by the DLLImport of urlmon.dll, I looked in pinvoke.net, and found: http://pinvoke.net/default.aspx/urlmon.UrlMkGetSessionOption

Called by:

```
namespace GetUserAgent
{
    class Program
    {
        //  The name of the program that was started by user
        //  See: Assembly.GetEntryAssembly Method ()
        //  https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.assembly.getentryassembly.aspx
        public static string ExecName
        {
            get
            {
                //  The name of the executable that was started by user
                return System.Reflection.Assembly.GetEntryAssembly().GetName().Name;
            }
        }

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            foreach (string arg in args)
            {
                if ((arg == "/?")
                    || (arg == "-?")
                    || (arg == "--help"))
                {
                    Console.Out.WriteLine(
                        "For /F \"tokens=*\" %%U In ('{0}') Do Set UserAgent=%%U",
                        ExecName);
                    return;
                }
            }

            string userAgent = UserAgent.Value;
            Console.Out.WriteLine(userAgent);
        }
    }
}
```

This generates the UserAgent value.  Argument /? shows how to use it in a command script.