# How to change WebBrowser control User Agent in C#

Tags: c#, winforms, webbrowser-control

I am a beginner in using WebBrowser Control in C#. I try to change the User Agent string in

a WebBrowser control in my Windows form. How can i do this ?

Please Help.

Comment: What have you tried? [duplicate](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/937573/changing-the-useragent-of-the-webbrowser-control-winforms-c-sharp)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can set any additional headers in the Navigate method of WebBrowser

```
WebBrowser wc = new WebBrowser();
wc.Navigate("http://google.com", null, null, "User-Agent: User agent");
```

Comment: its does not load the mobile version of the websites