# WebBrowser is asking for credentials on every page

Tags: c#, wpf, webbrowser-control

I'm using web browser control and this is constructor of the form which hosts web browser control:

```
string user = "xxx";
string pass = "xxx";
string authHdr = "Authorization: Basic " + Convert.ToBase64String(Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(user + ":" + pass)) + "\r\n";
myBrowser.Navigate("http://xxx.xxx.xxx/homepage", null, null, authHdr);
```

Browser opens first page (homepage, using myBrowser.Navigate()) successfully, but when I click any link on this page it asks me for credentials again. Is there any method or property for setting credentials for all navigating actions?

Comment: Have you tried [this approach](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/937573/changing-the-useragent-of-the-webbrowser-control-winforms-c-sharp)?

Comment: "xxx" sounds like a naughty user name and password :P

Comment: @HighCore :) maybe i should put more x's