# IWebbrowser2 IE=edge and User agent string

Tags: c++, winapi, webbrowser-control, user-agent, iwebbrowser2

I'm developping a winapi c++ program that uses IWebBrowser2 embedded control.

I'm running Windows 7 + IExplore 11 so when I open IE11 and call to my server I get this User Agent string:

```
Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; Trident/7.0; rv:11.0) like Gecko
```

When making requests from IWebBrowser2 I get this UA String:

```
Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 7.0; Windows NT 6.1; Trident/7.0; SLCC2; .NET CLR 2.0.50727; .NET CLR 3.5.30729; .NET CLR 3.0.30729; Media Center PC 6.0; .NET4.0C; Tablet PC 2.0; InfoPath.3; .NET4.0E)
```

I've managed to append this meta tag to every html page loaded in IWebBrowser2 (**EDIT** trying to avoid doing Browser Feature Controls -see comments-):

```
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge"/>
```

**First question**: by doing this, do I enable features for the latest installed IExplore version?

**Second question**: I've seen in [Changing the user agent of the WebBrowser control](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/937573/changing-the-user-agent-of-the-webbrowser-control) how to change the UA string in IWebBrowser2.

Is there any way to get the latest IE version UA string in a safe user permission? (so even for most permission restricted user accounts I could achieve).
I've tried with [ObtainUserAgentString()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms775114%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) with no luck, always getting `"Mozilla/4.0 ... MSIE 7.0 ..."`

Comment: **First question**: You need to implement Browser Feature Control: http://stackoverflow.com/a/18333982/1768303, **second question**, not sure I fully understand what you're asking, but hopefully the 1st one fixes it too.

Comment: Thanks, @Noseratio. The Browser FC needs some keys to be written in the registry. I'm not an expert in windows security but I thought that maybe this will require user account rights and this is what I'm trying to avoid with `IE=edge`. My first question is about if this will have the same effect as Browser FC. Maybe I'm wrong and no account rights are required? I will clarify the question

Comment: no admin rights required for `HKEY_CURRENT_USER`.

Comment: What about Question # 2? I am also interested in changing the user agent

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Finally and thanks to Noseratio comment (+1), I implemented Browser Feature Control as this does not require admin rights. I also opened the keys in the registry as volatile to not leaving registry dirty after possible uninstall.

As the response linked by Noseratio reffers to C#, I leave here the C++ translation if someone needs it with explanations of what each feature is doing:

```
static bool SetBrowserFeatureControlKey(wstring feature, wchar_t *appName, DWORD value) {
  HKEY key;
  bool success = true;
  wstring featuresPath(L"Software\\Microsoft\\Internet Explorer\\Main\\FeatureControl\\");
  wstring path(featuresPath + feature);

  LONG nError = RegCreateKeyEx(HKEY_CURRENT_USER, path.c_str(), 0, NULL, REG_OPTION_VOLATILE, KEY_WRITE, NULL, &key, NULL);
  if (nError != ERROR_SUCCESS) {
    success = false;

  } else {
    nError = RegSetValueExW(key, appName, 0, REG_DWORD, (const BYTE*) &value, sizeof(value));
    if (nError != ERROR_SUCCESS) {
      success = false;
    }

    nError = RegCloseKey(key);
    if (nError != ERROR_SUCCESS) {
      success = false;
    }
  } 

  return success;
}

static void SetBrowserFeatureControl() {
  // http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee330720(v=vs.85).aspx
  DWORD emulationMode = GetBrowserEmulationMode();

  if (emulationMode > 0) {
    // FeatureControl settings are per-process
    wchar_t fileName[MAX_PATH + 1];
    ZeroMemory(fileName, (MAX_PATH + 1) * sizeof(wchar_t));
    GetModuleFileNameW(NULL, fileName, 256);
    vector<string> splittedFileName = split(WString2string(fileName), '\\');
    ZeroMemory(fileName, (MAX_PATH + 1) * sizeof(wchar_t));
    wstring exeName = String2wstring(splittedFileName.at(splittedFileName.size() - 1));
    memcpy(fileName, exeName.c_str(), sizeof(wchar_t) * exeName.length());

    // make the control is not running inside Visual Studio Designer
    //if (String.Compare(fileName, "devenv.exe", true) == 0 || String.Compare(fileName, "XDesProc.exe", true) == 0) {
    //  return;
    //}

    // Windows Internet Explorer 8 and later. The FEATURE_BROWSER_EMULATION feature defines the default emulation mode for Internet
    // Explorer and supports the following values.
    // Webpages containing standards-based !DOCTYPE directives are displayed in IE10 Standards mode.
    SetBrowserFeatureControlKey(L"FEATURE_BROWSER_EMULATION", fileName, emulationMode);

    // Internet Explorer 8 or later. The FEATURE_AJAX_CONNECTIONEVENTS feature enables events that occur when the value of the online
    // property of the navigator object changes, such as when the user chooses to work offline. For more information, see the ononline
    // and onoffline events.
    // Default: DISABLED
    SetBrowserFeatureControlKey(L"FEATURE_AJAX_CONNECTIONEVENTS", fileName, 1);

    // Internet Explorer 9. Internet Explorer 9 optimized the performance of window-drawing routines that involve clipping regions associated
    // with child windows. This helped improve the performance of certain window drawing operations. However, certain applications hosting the
    // WebBrowser Control rely on the previous behavior and do not function correctly when these optimizations are enabled. The
    // FEATURE_ENABLE_CLIPCHILDREN_OPTIMIZATION feature can disable these optimizations.
    // Default: ENABLED
    // SetBrowserFeatureControlKey(L"FEATURE_ENABLE_CLIPCHILDREN_OPTIMIZATION", fileName, 1);

    // Internet Explorer 8 and later. By default, Internet Explorer reduces memory leaks caused by circular references between Internet Explorer
    // and the Microsoft JScript engine, especially in scenarios where a webpage defines an expando and the page is refreshed. If a legacy
    // application no longer functions with these changes, the FEATURE_MANAGE_SCRIPT_CIRCULAR_REFS feature can disable these improvements.
    // Default: ENABLED
    // SetBrowserFeatureControlKey(L"FEATURE_MANAGE_SCRIPT_CIRCULAR_REFS", fileName, 1);

    // Windows Internet Explorer 8. When enabled, the FEATURE_DOMSTORAGE feature allows Internet Explorer and applications hosting the WebBrowser
    // Control to use the Web Storage API. For more information, see Introduction to Web Storage.
    // Default: ENABLED
    // SetBrowserFeatureControlKey(L"FEATURE_DOMSTORAGE ", fileName, 1);

    // Internet Explorer 9. The FEATURE_GPU_RENDERING feature enables Internet Explorer to use a graphics processing unit (GPU) to render content.
    // This dramatically improves performance for webpages that are rich in graphics.
    // Default: DISABLED
    SetBrowserFeatureControlKey(L"FEATURE_GPU_RENDERING ", fileName, 1);

    // Internet Explorer 9. By default, the WebBrowser Control uses Microsoft DirectX to render webpages, which might cause problems for
    // applications that use the Draw method to create bitmaps from certain webpages. In Internet Explorer 9, this method returns a bitmap
    // (in a Windows Graphics Device Interface (GDI) wrapper) instead of a GDI metafile representation of the webpage. When the
    // FEATURE_IVIEWOBJECTDRAW_DMLT9_WITH_GDI feature is enabled, the following conditions cause the Draw method to use GDI instead of DirectX
    // to create the resulting representation. The GDI representation will contain text records and vector data, but is not guaranteed to be
    // similar to the same represenation returned in earlier versions of the browser:
    //    The device context passed to the Draw method points to an enhanced metafile.
    //    The webpage is not displayed in IE9 Standards mode.
    // By default, this feature is ENABLED for applications hosting the WebBrowser Control. This feature is ignored by Internet Explorer and
    // Windows Explorer. To enable this feature by using the registry, add the name of your executable file to the following setting.
    SetBrowserFeatureControlKey(L"FEATURE_IVIEWOBJECTDRAW_DMLT9_WITH_GDI  ", fileName, 0);

    // Windows 8 introduces a new input model that is different from the Windows 7 input model. In order to provide the broadest compatibility
    // for legacy applications, the WebBrowser Control for Windows 8 emulates the Windows 7 mouse, touch, and pen input model (also known as the
    // legacy input model). When the legacy input model is in effect, the following conditions are true:
    //    Windows pointer messages are not processed by the Trident rendering engine (mshtml.dll).
    //    Document Object Model (DOM) pointer and gesture events do not fire.
    //    Mouse and touch messages are dispatched according to the Windows 7 input model.
    //    Touch selection follows the Windows 7 model ("drag to select") instead of the Windows 8 model ("tap to select").
    //    Hardware accelerated panning and zooming is disabled.
    //    The Zoom and Pan Cascading Style Sheets (CSS) properties are ignored.
    // The FEATURE_NINPUT_LEGACYMODE feature control determines whether the legacy input model is enabled
    // Default: ENABLED
    SetBrowserFeatureControlKey(L"FEATURE_NINPUT_LEGACYMODE", fileName, 0);

    // Internet Explorer 7 consolidated HTTP compression and data manipulation into a centralized component in order to improve performance and
    // to provide greater consistency between transfer encodings (such as HTTP no-cache headers). For compatibility reasons, the original
    // implementation was left in place. When the FEATURE_DISABLE_LEGACY_COMPRESSION feature is disabled, the original compression implementation
    // is used.
    // Default: ENABLED
    // SetBrowserFeatureControlKey(L"FEATURE_DISABLE_LEGACY_COMPRESSION", fileName, 1);

    // When the FEATURE_LOCALMACHINE_LOCKDOWN feature is enabled, Internet Explorer applies security restrictions on content loaded from the
    // user's local machine, which helps prevent malicious behavior involving local files:
    //    Scripts, Microsoft ActiveX controls, and binary behaviors are not allowed to run.
    //    Object safety settings cannot be overridden.
    //    Cross-domain data actions require confirmation from the user.
    // Default: DISABLED
    // SetBrowserFeatureControlKey(L"FEATURE_LOCALMACHINE_LOCKDOWN", fileName, 0);

    // Internet Explorer 7 and later. When enabled, the FEATURE_BLOCK_LMZ_??? feature allows ??? stored in the Local Machine zone to be
    // loaded only by webpages loaded from the Local Machine zone or by webpages hosted by sites in the Trusted Sites list. For more information,
    // see Security and Compatibility in Internet Explorer 7.
    // Default: DISABLED
    //    FEATURE_BLOCK_LMZ_IMG can block images that try to load from the user's local file system. To opt in, add your process name and set 
    //                          the value to 0x00000001.
    //    FEATURE_BLOCK_LMZ_OBJECT can block objects that try to load from the user's local file system. To opt in, add your process name and
    //                          set the value to 0x00000001.
    //    FEATURE_BLOCK_LMZ_SCRIPT can block script access from the user's local file system. To opt in, add your process name and set the value
    //                          to 0x00000001.
    // SetBrowserFeatureControlKey(L"FEATURE_BLOCK_LMZ_OBJECT", fileName, 0);
    // SetBrowserFeatureControlKey(L"FEATURE_BLOCK_LMZ_OBJECT", fileName, 0);
    // SetBrowserFeatureControlKey(L"FEATURE_BLOCK_LMZ_SCRIPT", fileName, 0);

    // Internet Explorer 8 and later. When enabled, the FEATURE_DISABLE_NAVIGATION_SOUNDS feature disables the sounds played when you open a
    // link in a webpage.
    // Default: DISABLED
    SetBrowserFeatureControlKey(L"FEATURE_DISABLE_NAVIGATION_SOUNDS", fileName, 1);

    // Windows Internet Explorer 7 and later. Prior to Internet Explorer 7, href attributes of a objects supported the javascript prototcol;
    // this allowed webpages to execute script when the user clicked a link. For security reasons, this support was disabled in Internet
    // Explorer 7. For more information, see Event 1034 - Cross-Domain Barrier and Script URL Mitigation.
    // When enabled, the FEATURE_SCRIPTURL_MITIGATION feature allows the href attribute of a objects to support the javascript prototcol. 
    // Default: DISABLED
    SetBrowserFeatureControlKey(L"FEATURE_SCRIPTURL_MITIGATION", fileName, 1);

    // For Windows 8 and later, the FEATURE_SPELLCHECKING feature controls this behavior for Internet Explorer and for applications hosting
    // the web browser control (WebOC). When fully enabled, this feature automatically corrects grammar issues and identifies misspelled words
    // for the conditions described earlier.
    //    (DWORD) 00000000 - Features are disabled.
    //    (DWORD) 00000001 - Features are enabled for the conditions described earlier. (This is the default value.)
    //    (DWORD) 00000002 - Features are enabled, but only for elements that specifically set the spellcheck attribute to true.
    SetBrowserFeatureControlKey(L"FEATURE_SPELLCHECKING", fileName, 0);

    // When enabled, the FEATURE_STATUS_BAR_THROTTLING feature limits the frequency of status bar updates to one update every 200 milliseconds.
    // Default: DISABLED
    SetBrowserFeatureControlKey(L"FEATURE_STATUS_BAR_THROTTLING", fileName, 1);

    // Internet Explorer 7 or later. When enabled, the FEATURE_TABBED_BROWSING feature enables tabbed browsing navigation shortcuts and
    // notifications. For more information, see Tabbed Browsing for Developers.
    // Default: DISABLED
    // SetBrowserFeatureControlKey(L"FEATURE_TABBED_BROWSING", fileName, 1);

    // When enabled, the FEATURE_VALIDATE_NAVIGATE_URL feature control prevents Windows Internet Explorer from navigating to a badly formed URL.
    // Default: DISABLED
    SetBrowserFeatureControlKey(L"FEATURE_VALIDATE_NAVIGATE_URL", fileName, 1);

    // When enabled,the FEATURE_WEBOC_DOCUMENT_ZOOM feature allows HTML dialog boxes to inherit the zoom state of the parent window.
    // Default: DISABLED
    SetBrowserFeatureControlKey(L"FEATURE_WEBOC_DOCUMENT_ZOOM", fileName, 1);

    // The FEATURE_WEBOC_POPUPMANAGEMENT feature allows applications hosting the WebBrowser Control to receive the default Internet Explorer
    // pop-up window management behavior.
    // Default: ENABLED
    SetBrowserFeatureControlKey(L"FEATURE_WEBOC_POPUPMANAGEMENT", fileName, 0);

    // Applications hosting the WebBrowser Control should ensure that window resizing and movement events are handled appropriately for the
    // needs of the application. By default, these events are ignored if the WebBrowser Control is not hosted in a proper container. When enabled,
    // the FEATURE_WEBOC_MOVESIZECHILD feature allows these events to affect the parent window of the application hosting the WebBrowser Control.
    // Because this can lead to unpredictable results, it is not considered desirable behavior.
    // Default: DISABLED
    // SetBrowserFeatureControlKey(L"FEATURE_WEBOC_MOVESIZECHILD", fileName, 0);

    // The FEATURE_ADDON_MANAGEMENT feature enables applications hosting the WebBrowser Control
    // to respect add-on management selections made using the Add-on Manager feature of Internet Explorer.
    // Add-ons disabled by the user or by administrative group policy will also be disabled in applications that enable this feature.
    SetBrowserFeatureControlKey(L"FEATURE_ADDON_MANAGEMENT", fileName, 0); 

    // Internet Explorer 10. When enabled, the FEATURE_WEBSOCKET feature allows script to create and use WebSocket objects.
    // The WebSocketobject allows websites to request data across domains from your browser by using the WebSocket protocol.
    // Default: ENABLED
    SetBrowserFeatureControlKey(L"FEATURE_WEBSOCKET", fileName, 1);

    // When enabled, the FEATURE_WINDOW_RESTRICTIONS feature adds several restrictions to the size and behavior of popup windows:
    //    Popup windows must appear in the visible display area.
    //    Popup windows are forced to have status and address bars.
    //    Popup windows must have minimum sizes.
    //    Popup windows cannot cover important areas of the parent window.
    // When enabled, this feature can be configured differently for each security zone by using the URLACTION_FEATURE_WINDOW_RESTRICTIONS URL
    // action flag. 
    // Default: ENABLED
    SetBrowserFeatureControlKey(L"FEATURE_WINDOW_RESTRICTIONS", fileName, 0);

    // Internet Explorer 7 and later. The FEATURE_XMLHTTP feature enables or disables the native XMLHttpRequest object.
    // Default: ENABLED
    // SetBrowserFeatureControlKey(L"FEATURE_XMLHTTP", fileName, 1);
  }
}

static LONG GetDWORDRegKey(HKEY hKey, const std::wstring &strValueName, DWORD &nValue, DWORD nDefaultValue) {
  nValue = nDefaultValue;
  DWORD dwBufferSize(sizeof(DWORD));
  DWORD nResult(0);
  LONG nError = ::RegQueryValueExW(hKey, strValueName.c_str(), 0, NULL, reinterpret_cast<LPBYTE>(&nResult), &dwBufferSize);
  if (ERROR_SUCCESS == nError) {
    nValue = nResult;
  }

  return nError;
}

static LONG GetStringRegKey(HKEY hKey, const std::wstring &strValueName, std::wstring &strValue, const std::wstring &strDefaultValue) {
  strValue = strDefaultValue;
  WCHAR szBuffer[512];
  DWORD dwBufferSize = sizeof(szBuffer);
  ULONG nError;
  nError = RegQueryValueExW(hKey, strValueName.c_str(), 0, NULL, (LPBYTE)szBuffer, &dwBufferSize);
  if (ERROR_SUCCESS == nError) {
    strValue = szBuffer;
  }
  return nError;
}

static DWORD GetBrowserEmulationMode() {
  int browserVersion = 7;
  wstring sBrowserVersion;
  HKEY key;
  bool success = true;
  BYTE data[256];
  wstring path(L"SOFTWARE\\Microsoft\\Internet Explorer");
  LONG nError = RegOpenKeyExW(HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE, path.c_str(), 0, KEY_QUERY_VALUE, &key);
  DWORD mode = 10000; // Internet Explorer 10. Webpages containing standards-based !DOCTYPE directives are displayed in IE10 Standards mode. Default value for Internet Explorer 10.

  if (nError != ERROR_SUCCESS) {
    success = false;
  } else {
    nError = GetStringRegKey(key, L"svcVersion", sBrowserVersion, L"7");
    if (nError != ERROR_SUCCESS) {
      nError = GetStringRegKey(key, L"version", sBrowserVersion, L"7");
      if (nError != ERROR_SUCCESS) {
        success = false;
      }
    }

   if (RegCloseKey(key) != ERROR_SUCCESS) {
      success = false;
    }
  }

  if (success) {
    browserVersion = std::atoi(split(WString2string(sBrowserVersion), '.').at(0).c_str()); // convert base 16 number in s to int

    switch (browserVersion) {
    case 7:
      mode = 7000; // Webpages containing standards-based !DOCTYPE directives are displayed in IE7 Standards mode. Default value for applications hosting the WebBrowser Control.
      break;
    case 8:
      mode = 8000; // Webpages containing standards-based !DOCTYPE directives are displayed in IE8 mode. Default value for Internet Explorer 8
      break;
    case 9:
      mode = 9000; // Internet Explorer 9. Webpages containing standards-based !DOCTYPE directives are displayed in IE9 mode. Default value for Internet Explorer 9.
      break;
    default:
      // use IE10 mode by default
      break;
    }

  } else {
    mode = -1;
  }

  return mode;
}
```

Comment: Would this apply to all applications that are run, not just yours?

Comment: // FeatureControl settings are per-process

Comment: Ahh, my bad, I just barely skimmed it the first time, for those playing at home, it's the GetModuleFileNameW part, I also read some other articles about it, we reference our app with something like "myapp.exe".

Comment: You're right, in case you're in a dll, maybe you could pass it as a function argument and even create a sepparate function to get the name... This was a little straight forward case :)