# Windows 8 phone c# request desktop website not working

Tags: c#, url, windows-phone-8, browser

How do I request the desktop website instead of the mobile website in the webBrowser component. I have tried adding "=desktop" after the url but this makes not effect.

```
String url = "http://www.google.com"; // This could be any website url
Browser.Navigate(New Uri(url + "=desktop", UriKind.Absolute));
```

Thank you in advance :)

If you need any more details please comment and I will be happy to explain in further detail :)

Comment: You need to set `User-Agent` like [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/937573/changing-the-user-agent-of-the-webbrowser-control) (Not sure if it would work for WP8)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For some websites, use the desktop version User-Agent can fix this problem.

Try this:

```
Browser.Navigate(new Uri(MainUri, UriKind.Absolute), null, "User-Agent:Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; MSIE 10.0; Windows NT 6.1; Trident/6.0)");
```

I just navigate to google with IE10's UA and it responses with desktop version.

Answer (score 1):

```
Browser.Navigate(new Uri(MainUri, UriKind.Absolute), null, "User-Agent:Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; MSIE 10.0; Windows NT 6.1; Trident/6.0)");
```

This should work! FOr most websites

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
Browser.Navigate(new Uri(MainUri, UriKind.Absolute), null, "User-Agent:Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; MSIE 10.0; Windows NT 6.1; Trident/6.0)");
```

I just navigate to google with IE10's UA and it responses with desktop version.