# How to change the UserAgent in WebBrowser control in Window's Desktop Application?

Tags: c#, .net, windows, desktop-application

I am developing application for windows with Windows 10 and i am using web browser control to navigate the URL. I just want to change the User Agent from Edge to Chrome . Is there any way to do that ?

```
            webBrowser1.Navigate("www.anywebsite.com", null, null, "User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/41.0.2228.0 Safari/537.36");
            btnRead.Enabled = true;
```

I also done trying this but it is not working.

Comment: What you have would work, but only for the first request.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Changing the user agent of the WebBrowser control](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/937573/changing-the-user-agent-of-the-webbrowser-control)