# How to detect the users' EdgeHTML version?

Tags: .net, winforms, webbrowser-control, user-agent

I have a Winforms application which is deployed via ClickOnce. Once the user launches the application they enter their credentials and then we check a registry key to determine what version of IE they have. We use this for some `WebBrowser` controls in the winform application.

With the advent of Windows 10 + Edge, we need to support this browser now. Unlike IE, Edge does not write this information to the registry so we can't check that.

I saw [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/937573/changing-the-user-agent-of-the-webbrowser-control) but I don't think that's what we want. It looks like in this case the question asker already *knows* the user-agent string but was simply having trouble "keeping track of it".

So, how can I get the EdgeHTML version from a winform application?