# VB.NET, How to change the User-agent of the web browser control

Tags: .net, vb.net

There is a way to change The **User-Agent** of web browser control and it works!
I changed the **User-Agent** by using the following code:

```
WebBrowser1.Navigate("https://example.com/file.php", Nothing, Nothing, "User-Agent: Your User-Agent" + vbCrLf)
```

It works, But the problem is that this code works one time!

For example if you entered to this site "https://example.com/login.php" and the site has referred you to another page! The second page will use the default **User-Agent** of Microsoft visual studio

Let me clarify this,The problem is that the code shown above cannot use the User-Agent more than once, After the site redirect you to another page the web browser will use the default **User-Agent**

Comment: I checked out this before, I can't understand C#, thank you very much my dear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can call the `UrlMkSetSessionOption` API function as described [here](http://www.lukepaynesoftware.com/articles/programming-tutorials/changing-the-user-agent-in-a-web-browser-control/), and additionally use `URLMON_OPTION_USERAGENT_REFRESH` to avoid the renavigation problem described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18080830/1871033):

```vb
Module UserAgentChanger
    <Runtime.InteropServices.DllImport("urlmon.dll", CharSet:=Runtime.InteropServices.CharSet.Ansi)>
    Private Function UrlMkSetSessionOption(
        ByVal dwOption As Integer,
        ByVal pBuffer As String,
        ByVal dwBufferLength As Integer,
        ByVal dwReserved As Integer) As Integer
    End Function

    Const URLMON_OPTION_USERAGENT As Integer = &H10000001
    Const URLMON_OPTION_USERAGENT_REFRESH As Integer = &H10000002

    Public Sub SetUserAgent(ByVal UserAgent As String)
        UrlMkSetSessionOption(URLMON_OPTION_USERAGENT_REFRESH, vbNullString, 0, 0)
        UrlMkSetSessionOption(URLMON_OPTION_USERAGENT, UserAgent, UserAgent.Length, 0)
    End Sub
End Module
```